# IBM Worklight - Build failure with Adobe Air

Tags: air, adobe, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on a Worklight hybrid application. In this setup I have already set the environment path for the Adobe Air SDK. I am following these steps:

1. Download the Adobe Air SDK from the Air SDK on Adobe website.
2. Unpack the archive into a folder of your choice.
3. Set an environment variable (either locally or on the central build server) named AIR_HOME, pointing to the place where you opened the SDK. The Worklight® Builder uses this environment variable to run the build and sign tool when building AIR applications.

And this is the build error I get in Eclipse:

> E: air build failed: The path provided in the environment variable
>   'AIR_HOME' is not valid. Ensure that the provided path points to the
>   root folder of the installed Adobe AIR SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Windows 7 machine and using Worklight 6.1, I have the following set in `System Properties > Environment Variables... > System variables`. The build passed successfully.

Variable: AIR_HOME
Value: C:\WorklightDev\AdobeAir (the root folder where the SDK was extracted to)

Once building the environment, you will see the following message:

> A dummy certificate is used to sign the air application because a
>   PKCS12 certificate from a certificate authority is not available. To
>   use a certificate, set the `<certificate>` element under the `<air>`
>   element in `application-descriptor.xml`.

This is **not an error** but a **warning**.

It means what it means - that you did not provide a certificate for your application, so a dummy certificate is being used instead.

See the following Information Center topic: [Signing Adobe Air applications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_signing_adobe_air_applications.html)

> Adobe AIR applications must be digitally signed in order for users to
>   install them. IBM® Worklight provides a default certificate for
>   signing AIR applications that can be used for development and test
>   purposes.
>
> To sign an AIR application for production distribution, using your own
>   certificate, follow these instructions:
>
> 1. Obtain a PKCS12 certificate from a certificate authority ([see here for more information](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff0.html)),
>      and export it as a PFX file.
> 2. Place this certificate on your hard disk.
> 3. Set the `<certificate>` element under the `<air>` element in
>      `application-descriptor.xml`
>
> The structure of the `<certificate>` element is:
>
> `<certificate password="password" PFXFilePath="path-to-pfx"/>`
>
> where `password` is the password for the PFX certificate, and `path-to-pfx` can
>   either be relative to the root of the application, or an absolute
>   path.

Find the time to familiarize yourself with Worklight. This is not optional.
Read the following:

- [IBM Worklight Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html)
- [IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp)

Comment: Also documented here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/devenv/t_installing_tools_for_adobe_air.html?resultof=%22%41%64%6f%62%65%22%20%22%61%64%6f%62%22%20

Comment: Hi Adar Thank you very much giving response,environment issue is closed next signing exception raising  how to resolve ?  5W: A dummy certificate is used to sign the air application because a PKCS12 certificate from a certificate authority is not 
available. To use a certificate, set the <certificate> element under the <air> element in application-descriptor.xml.

Comment: sorry adar i am new in worklight platform ,its working fine.Thank you very much for kind support.

Comment: Hi Adar, I am using MobileFirst 7.1 in MAC. Getting the same error. echo $AIR_HOME /Users/pragupathi/AdobeAir